# In IE11,IE10 Page postbacks occur when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, autocomplete, enter

In my code on running from local Postback did not occur on button trigger click,but when i run through production url and click button complete Postback occurs.How to handle page postback in IE11,IE10.In all the other browsers it works fine with no postback of page.I googled ut did not get the solution for IE.

Comment: Put some relevant code in your question. Like this is the button and I have written this code etc.

Answer (score 0):

keep your all controls into update panel

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</form>
```